# Programatic Scrolling of an HTML Table with Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I have done extensive Google searches and implemented a number of solutions found here at stack overflow and at other sites but  have not been able to get my table to scroll under program control.

I am implementing a scrolling table of variable names to use in a plot. I have 200+ variables so I want users to be able to type some fragment of a variable's name and show that variable in the list by scrolling. I have this all working except the scrolling part.

This is what a table looks like:

http://www.oceanatlas.com/images/list1.png

This is the HTML that defines the table:

```
<div id="ySeriesParamChooser" class="ParamChooser">
  <table id="yparamtable" cellspacing="0" border="1" >
    <thead class="fixedHeader">
      <tr>
         <th colspan="3">Primary Y Axis</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="scrollContent" style="text-align: center;">
       <tr>
           <td>Cell Content 1</td>
           <td>Cell Content 2</td>
           <td>Cell Content 3</td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I create the contents of the table programatically using Javascript. As you can see from the image link above the table looks and functions as I designed.

Here is the some relevant CSS:

```
html>body tbody.scrollContent {
    display: block;
    height: 193px;
    overflow: auto;
    table-layout: fixed;
    font-family: Helvetica, Palatino, Arial, sans-serif; 
    font-size: 0.8em;     
    width: 100%
}

.ParamChooser {
     padding: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
     float:left;
     font-family: Droid Sans, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
     font-size: .8em;
     cursor:default;
 }
```

What I have tried:

```
// this code correctly find the nth <tr> in the table
var symTarg = "#" + this.jqSel ;
var row = $(symTarg).find('tr').eq(n);

row.scrollIntoView();   // this doesn’t do anything

// this didn’t do anything
var scrollTarg = "#" + this.jqSel + “.scrolltable";  // jqSel == "yparamtable"
var row = $(symTarg).find('tr').eq(n);
if (row.length) {
    $(scrollTarg).scrollTop(row.offset().top - ($(scrollTarg).height()/2));
 }

// tried this to see if I could just scroll to the last row
var symTarg = "#" + this.jqSel ;  // jqSel == "yparamtable"
var rowpos = $(symTarg).find('tr:last').position();  // finds last <tr>
var content = $(symTarg).find('tbody.scrollcontent');
$(content).scrollTop(rowpos.top);
```

So, what am I doing wrong? I am an experienced programmer but  new to UI programming in Javascript.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I hope you enjoy your stay.  No, you're done nothing wrong. Feel free to comment on an answer if you need clarification, and don't forget to upvote and / or accept good answers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fiddle of the scrolling working : https://jsfiddle.net/070vx0oo/7/

First, in order to scroll to a specific element, you have to select only the element and not its parent, to get its position :

```
var rowpos = $('.scrollContent > tr:eq(4)').position(); // finds the 5th <tr> child of .scrollContent
```

Here the elements are the TRs. The position is relative to the first parent, which is .scrollContent (tbody)

Then, we need to scroll INTO this parent. So we select `.scrollContent` which is the parent we are talking about, and use `scrollTop()`.

```
var content = $('.scrollContent');
$(content).scrollTop(rowpos.top);
```

So we scroll to the position of our TD.

Also note that I had to add this CSS to our parent (remember, the one called `.scrollContent`) so that we can scroll into it.

```
.scrollContent{
  display:block; /* Allows us to resize the element */
  overflow: auto; /* Automatically adds scrollbars if content overflows */
  height:100px; /* Our custom table height */
  position:relative; /* Important ! so javascript get accurate position */
}
```

Now you just have to implement it in your own JavaScript, by selecting the correct TR for `var rows`.

I hope it helped you to understand.

Comment: Thank you for your response but I have to admit that I am a bit more confused.   You have inverted my understanding of the tr and td tags. I create tr tags to hold rows that have multiple columns that contain the var name, a selection checkmark, and a link to a UI to allows the variable's style to be edited (see link). That's why I search for a matching <tr> whereas you are searching for a matching <td>. Can you provide an example of how I can make the <tr>s scroll? Thanks again! [link](http://www.oceanatlas.com/List_with_cols.png)

Comment: Of course I adapted my code to your HTML structure, and according to the picture you gave. So yes, a tr should basically be just a row, and contain multiple td inside. But based on the picture and your HTML I thought there was only one column. But as I mentioned in my answer, you just have to select the correct parent. I'm going to edit it.

Comment: Sorry about that...I thought everything happened at the row level so I omitted the columns which are created programatically. Your code though did give me the clue I needed to solve my problem and it was exactly as you suggested--I wasn't selecting the right parent. I changed my selector for the scroll content to:                                                                              var scrollTarg = "#" + this.jqSel + " > tbody"; and now it works! Thank you!

Comment: Sorry newbie question--how do I mark as answered? Do I use the Answer Your Question button?